# Can I make Istio 1.4.10 local rate limit?

Tags: istio, envoyproxy, istio-sidecar

I'm working on istio 1.4.10, I need local rate limit replace nginx rate limit.
Istio 1.4.10 explain just grobal rate limit via redis.

but recent doc explain local rate limit with envoy.
So Can i make custom local rate limit envoyFilter ?